# Наследование, fread

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть базовый класс, в котором есть метод сохранения/загрузки с файла. И есть второй класс который наследуется. Вопрос: как правильно переопределить метод загрузки с файла? Ошибку в своем коде я вижу, но не знаю как правильно можно сделать. Пример кода:

```
    void media::Load()// базовый
    {
        system("cls");
        char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.bin";
        FILE *f1 = nullptr;
        fopen_s(&f1, filename, "rb");
        if (f1 == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error: ");
            _getch();
            return;
        }
        fread(&name, 1, 20, f1);
        fread(&manufacturer, 1, 20, f1);
        fread(&model, 1, 20, f1);
        fread(&capacity, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
        fread(&quantity, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
        fclose(f1);
    }

void DVD::Load()
{
    system("cls");
    char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.bin";
    FILE *f1 = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&f1, filename, "rb");
    if (f1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        _getch();
        return;
    }
    media::Load();
    int a;
    fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
    setSpeedDVD(a);
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете отрефакторить ваш код так:

```
void media::Load()// базовый
{
    system("cls");
    char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.bin";
    FILE *f1 = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&f1, filename, "rb");
    if (f1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        _getch();
        return;
    }
    LoadDataFromFile(f1);
    fclose(f1);
}

// virtual, protected
void media::LoadDataFromFile(FILE* f1)
{
    fread(&name, 1, 20, f1);
    fread(&manufacturer, 1, 20, f1);
    fread(&model, 1, 20, f1);
    fread(&capacity, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
    fread(&quantity, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
}

// virtual, protected
void DVD::LoadDataFromFile(FILE* f1)
{
    media::LoadDataFromFile(f1);
    int a;
    fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
    setSpeedDVD(a);
}
```

При этом вам, судя по всему, не понадобится объявлять `media::load` виртуальным.

Comment: Спасибо, решение очень интересное!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!